# Normal closure of a 2-subnormal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

So, I have been trying to understand if this is true for quite sometime.

Suppose you have a group $G$ and a subgroup $H < G$. Suppose also that $H$ is normal on its normal closure, i.e. $$H\vartriangleleft H^G \vartriangleleft G$$

$H$ is then a 2-subnormal subgroup of $G$ and I saw that all 2-subnormal subgroups are conjugate-permutable, i.e.  $$ \forall g\in G\ ,\ H^g H = H H^g$$

**My question**: Does this mean that $$H^G = \prod_{g\in G} H^g\ \ ?$$

Thank you!

Comment: Yes that follows from the definition of $H^G$ as the group generated by all conjugates in $G$ of all elements of $H$. Since the conjugates are all permutable, the order of $g \in G$ in the product does not mattter.

Comment: Thank you for your help!